# Are integral representations of the Dirac Delta formally equivalent to the Dirac Delta distribution?

Tags: fourier-transform, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

I know that the Dirac Delta "function" $\delta(x)=\begin{cases}\infty&x=0\\0&x\neq0\end{cases},\int_{\Bbb{R}}\delta(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=1$ is supposedly a distribution, not a genuine function, (although I know nothing about distributions and what that really means). I also know that it has various integral representations, of which the one I know best I will present here:

$$\delta(\omega)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\Bbb{R}}\exp(it\cdot\omega)\,\rm{dt}$$

Formally I assume this integral does not actually exist for $\omega\neq0$, since $\lim_{n\to\pm\infty}\exp(in\cdot\omega)$ does not exist due to oscillating behaviour, so this representation raises some concerns for me. This representation is used to present answers to Fourier transforms, and that integral (which I do not believe exists) is "calculated" and whisked under the rug of Dirac Delta. Is this a correct way to define the distribution?

I am aware that in physics/engineering, it is common to heuristically use $\delta$ like this, with such representations, and treat it as a valid function, since the real world is too complex to treat everything with absolute rigour, but in the world of rigorous mathematics, I ask: is this correct?

For example:

$$\begin{align}\mathcal{F}(\cos)(\omega)&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\Bbb{R}}\cos(t)\exp(it\cdot\omega)\,\mathrm{dt}\\&=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\Bbb{R}}\exp(it(\omega+1))+\exp(it(\omega-1))\,\mathrm{dt}\\&\overset{\color{red}*}=\sqrt{\pi/2}\cdot(\delta(\omega+1)+\delta(\omega-1))\end{align}$$

Which correctly suggests that cosine consists of pure tones at the radial frequencies $\omega=\pm1$ (although the multiplication by $\sqrt{\pi/2}$ means what, exactly?)

Is this, namely the step denoted by $\color{red}*$, formal (in the context of distributions)? Or is this just some standard physicist's heuristic?

Many thanks! Note that I really do not know any distribution theory, but am just very curious at where the line between rigorous Dirac/Fourier and heuristic Dirac/Fourier is drawn!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "definition" you give of $\delta$ is not mathematically rigorous. The correct definition is that $\langle \delta, \phi \rangle = \phi(0)$ for all $\phi\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$ or $\phi\in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ when working with Fourier transforms. Here $\langle u, \phi \rangle$ is a pairing of a distribution $u$ with a test function $\phi,$ returning a number. It's a bit similar to inner products, but the objects are of different types. You can think of it as the integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}} u(x)\,\phi(x)\,dx.$

An ordinary function $f$ is considered as a distribution by
$\langle f, \phi \rangle := \int f(x) \, \phi(x) \, dx.$

The formula $\delta(\omega)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{i\omega t}\,dt$ is also not rigorous, but I would say that it is at least somewhat better as it can be interpreted within the theory of distributions as the inverse Fourier transform of constant function $\mathbf{1}(t) = 1.$

Fourier transforms of distributions are defined by moving the transform to the test function: $\langle \mathcal{F}u, \varphi \rangle = \langle u, \mathcal{F}\varphi \rangle.$ From this and the definition of $\delta$ above we get
$$
\langle \mathcal{F}\delta, \phi \rangle
= \langle \delta, \mathcal{F}\phi \rangle
= \mathcal{F}\phi(0)
= \left. \int \phi(t) e^{-i\omega t} \, dt \right|_{\omega=0}
= \int \phi(t) \, dt
= \langle \mathbf{1}, \phi \rangle.
$$
Now,
$$
\langle \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{i\omega t} dt, \phi(\omega) \rangle
= \langle \mathcal{F}\mathbf{1}(-\omega), \phi(\omega) \rangle
= \langle \mathbf{1}(-\omega), \mathcal{F}\phi(\omega) \rangle
= \langle \mathbf{1}(\omega), \mathcal{F}\phi(-\omega) \rangle
\\
= \langle \mathcal{F}\delta(\omega), \mathcal{F}\phi(-\omega) \rangle
= \langle \delta(\omega), \mathcal{F}\mathcal{F}\phi(-\omega) \rangle
= \langle \delta(\omega), 2\pi\phi(\omega) \rangle
= \langle 2\pi\delta(\omega), \phi(\omega) \rangle
,
$$
for every test function $\phi$ so $\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{i\omega t} dt=2\pi\delta(\omega)$ where the left hand side has been interpreted as $\mathcal{F}\mathbf{1}(-\omega).$

Thus, the integral itself is not rigorous, but there is a rigorous interpretation of it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What is $\mathcal{S}(\Bbb{R})$? And what about the Fourier transform of cosine that I showed? Was that rigorous/unrigorous? What would be more correct?

Comment: $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ is the [Schwartz space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space). It's closed under Fourier transforms.

Comment: The Fourier transform of $\cos$ can be made rigorous (although the integral you have is not), and the result is $\delta(\omega-1)+\delta(\omega+1)$ times some factor.

Comment: Thank you. So the heuristic Fourier transform I took has the correct answer but a non-rigorous method?

Comment: Yes, the answer is correct, but the calculations are non-rigorous (but I wouldn't say that they are incorrect).

Comment: Reading up on tempered distributions, Wikipedia states that, if you denote the continuous Fourier transform *and its transpose* by $\cal F$, then $(\mathcal{F}T)(\phi)=T(\mathcal{F}\phi)$ if $T$ is tempered. I see how this follows from the definition of transpose, except for two things: is the transpose of $\cal F$ the exact same integral operation, as suggested by your answer? If so why? and also why is this only the case if $T$ is tempered? Wikipedia neglects this kind of information sadly

Comment: The Fourier transform is only defined for tempered distributions. The reason is that Schwartz space $\mathcal{S}$ is closed under Fourier transforms while $C^\infty_c$ is not. There are distributions for which you cannot define the Fourier transform. One such is given by the function $e^x.$

Comment: If the distribution is given by an $L^1$ function then the transpose is given by the exact same integral. Try yourself to show that $\int \mathcal{F}f(\omega) \, g(\omega)\,d\omega=\int f(\omega)\,\mathcal{F}g(\omega)\,d\omega$ when $f,g$ are nice. On a distribution the integral isn't defined and instead the Fourier transform is defined by moving the transform to the test function. This is based on the previous formula.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129205/discussion-between-fshrike-and-md2perpe).